# Can't position UIImage through CGRect

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, cgrect

I'm trying to build a UIView of Social Media User's Profile and got stuck right in the beginning - when adding a User Image (UIImage) to my UIView. Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
import UIKit

class ProfileHeaderView: UIView {
    
    private lazy var profileImage: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "hipsterCat"))
        
        // Making Image Round
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3
                
        return imageView
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }
    
    private func setupView() {
        backgroundColor = .lightGray
        addSubview(profileImage)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        profileImage.frame = CGRect(
            x: bounds.midX - 64,
            y: bounds.midY - 64,
            width: 128,
            height: 128
        )
    }
}
```

My task is to use CGRect to position UIImage on the superView, yet once I run the project it just doesn't appear on the screen (only light gray background is there).

UIImageView is all right, the image appears when commenting layoutSubviews() override but it's not positioned.

Comment: Sorry If the question is way too dumb. This is my very first time using CGRect and seems like the whole purpose and idea of it is unclear to me.

Comment: Try resetting the image view's corner radius in `layoutSubViews` after updating the frame. And depending on the actual size of the image in the image view, you might need to set the image view's `contentMode` to `.scaleAspectFit` or `.scaleAspectFill`.

Comment: can you call "addSubview(profileImage)" in layoutsubviews() in end of function?

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar No, do not do that. `layoutSubviews` should not change add/remove subviews. It should only adjust their frames. The image view has already been added in `setupView`.

Comment: @HangarRash your advice actually worked! Updated my code with setting corner radius in `layoutSubViews` and it worked. Not sure that `.scaleAspectFill` is actually needed here cause if I comment it the layout is still just fine. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things that might have gotten wrong. The strangest result you are seeing is that you don't see the image at all once it is resized.

My best guess is that you are also setting the frame for the `ProfileHeaderView` instance. Note that there are 2 APIs for lay outing the views; one is using `frame` and the other one is auto layout. From auto layout a method `layoutSubviews` will be called. But using `frame` then only `frame` will be called. So you may be missing another override.

Try to add the following:

```
override var frame: CGRect {
    didSet {
        updateImagePosition()
    }
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    updateImagePosition()
}

private func updateImagePosition() {
    profileImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    profileImage.frame = CGRect(
        x: bounds.midX - 64,
        y: bounds.midY - 64,
        width: 128,
        height: 128
    )
    profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = 64
}
```

Next to adding an override for frame I have also added to option to determine content mode of your view. You might want to move that into your setup method but it is not too bad if it stays here. And the other one is setting corner radius which for sure needs to be set in here. Both mentioned by @HangarRash.

In the end it would be nice to have something like the following to be fair:

```
@IBDesignable
class ProfileHeaderView: UIView {
    
    @IBInspectable
    private var imageName: String = "hipsterCat" {
        didSet {
            profileImage.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    private var imageRadius: CGFloat = 64 {
        didSet {
            updateImagePosition()
        }
    }
    
    private lazy var profileImage: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: imageName))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3
        return imageView
    }()
    
    override var frame: CGRect {
        didSet {
            updateImagePosition()
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }
    
    private func setupView() {
        backgroundColor = .lightGray
        addSubview(profileImage)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateImagePosition()
    }
    
    private func updateImagePosition() {
        profileImage.frame = CGRect(
            x: bounds.midX - imageRadius,
            y: bounds.midY - imageRadius,
            width: imageRadius*2.0,
            height: imageRadius*2.0
        )
        profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = imageRadius
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it does work! The question I have is do we actually need `@IBDesignable` and `@ IBInspectable ` here? What's their purpose? (Sorry if it's a stupid question, I haven't worked with those yet).

Comment: @Philipp these two flags are designed to add support to your interface builder. You use Designable so that the view is actually drawn in your interface builder (Storyboard or Xib). The Inspectable is used so that you can set values within the interface builder; For each inspectable a new field is added which you can change. So you do not **need** it, I added it as nice-to-have code.

Answer (score 0):

I was following @HangarRash advice from the comments and managed to fix the issue. The thing I did is setting corner radius (and making image rounded) in `layoutSubViews` while also adding `.scaleAspectFill` to UIImageView. The final code is:

```
import UIKit

class ProfileHeaderView: UIView {
    
    private lazy var profileImage: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "hipsterCat"))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        
        return imageView
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }
    
    private func setupView() {
        backgroundColor = .lightGray
        addSubview(profileImage)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        profileImage.frame = CGRect(
            x: bounds.minX + 16,
            y: bounds.minY + 16,
            width: 128,
            height: 128
        )
        
        //Making image round
        profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = profileImage.frame.size.width / 2
        profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
        
        profileImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        profileImage.layer.borderWidth = 3
    }
}
```